# Is there any strategy for acquiring specific items?

Tags: star-trek-timelines

*This is about the **Star Trek: Timelines** mobile game*

When farming for a particular item, is there any strategy to how you should go after it? Or is it all RNG-based?

- Do faction stores cater to items for characters of that faction? E.g. Would an item for Worf, or any Klingon character, be more commonly found at the Klingon faction marketplace?
- Do Away Mission rewards lean towards the type of skill chosen for each mission roll? E.g. Will I have more luck getting a Dermal Regenerator from a mission's common rewards if I do more medical rolls rather than engineering/command/science etc?
- Do the type of characters chosen as bridge crew members in a space battle influence the type of reward? E.g. Will using R'Mor and Kirk (evasion and offense) give me a better chance at a "sciency" reward than I'd get using Kirk and Worf (offense and accuracy)?